# Issue trying to find a control inside a MasterPage

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, html

I am trying to change the DATA attribute in an html `<div>` tag using C# in the code-behind file for an asp.page.

This is my HTML Code

```
<div class="tile page-content" id="fullTextArticle"
                    data-ID=""
                    data-permission="" runat="server">
</div>
```

This is my c# in the code-behind file

```
private void DisplayFullTextArticle()
        {


            string contentID = "";

            if (Context.Request.QueryString["contentID"] != null)//check for a value in the query string
            {
                contentID = Context.Request.QueryString["contentID"];

                try 
                {

                    //define connection string                
                    string connString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))//create connection object
                    {

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spDisplayFullTextArticle", conn);

                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        conn.Open();

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(contentID);

                        SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        HtmlControl divDataID = FindControl(id: "fullTextArticle") as HtmlControl;


                        while (myReader.Read())
                        {
                            divDataID.Attributes["class"]= myReader["ID"].ToString();

                        }

                        myReader.Close();                      

                        //}//end using statement for SqlCommmand Object

                    }//end using statement for SQLConnection

                }//end try block

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                } //end catch block

            }//end if statement

}
```

Some context: My method gets a value from the query string and passes the value to a stored procedure which runs a SELECT query to pull full text content from a SQL database. I used break points to do some debugging and I can see the query string does pass the value to the procedure and it runs the query successfully. The trouble is that my HtmlControl variable, divDataID, ends up being null. So the ID value is not being set, so the `<div data-ID>` attribute is not being set in the browser.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? How do I set the data-ID attribute from the code-behind file?

Answer (score 0):

When you use Master pages finding controls is trickier. You should do something like this:

```
var divDataID = Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder").FindControl(id: "fullTextArticle") as HtmlControl;
```

Where `"ContentPlaceHolder"` is the ContentPlaceHolder ID in the master page.

Comment: Hi kblok. My original code does have the runat="server" attribute, but I forget to include in when I posted here (I've updated my post). My method in code behind is recognizing the <div> as a server control and is executing the stored procedure, its just that my HtmlControl variable, dataDivID is null. Do you have any idea how I can fix the problem?

Comment: @webguy is that div inside another Server Control? FindControl is not recursive. I've just tested that locally and it works.

Comment: The <div> is on a content page and no, it is not nestled inside another server control. However, in my master page, the <body> tag contains a <form runat=server> tag and in between that tag is the placeholder for the content page that is having the div problem I wrote about in this post.

Comment: @webguy check the new answer.

Comment: You are amazing!! Your solution to specify the Master Page placeholder ID did the trick. It works beautifully!! I was stuck on this for so long and you made it simple and easy to fix. I really appreciate all your help! This post should help other coders on here because this scenario is unique and has never been addressed before.

Comment: This might seem foolish, but I checked the FAQ and I can't find instructions on how to mark the question as valid. There is a green check mark in my control panel near the question I posted. Maybe this was done automatically..?

Comment: @webguy You should see a Check at the left of this answer,under the upvote votecount and downvote links. If not maybe it's because of your rep.